# How do I merge two rows based on a column match.(Google Spreadsheet)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that gets values through two forms it looks something like that:

```
ID        |Name     | Agreement
2324      |Lina     |
2324      |         |I agree
```

I want to achieve this :

```
ID        |Name     | Agreement
2324      |Lina     | I agree
```

I want to merge any two rows that have the same ID value,
I'm new to google sheets , so any help is so much appreciated.

The code I'm using to get data from form:

```
function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1
    Logger.log(nextRow);

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])
    Logger.log(newRow)

    sendEmails();

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

Comment: In your question, the sample situation has 2 same IDs. But, when there are more than 3 same IDs, what result do you retrieve? Or such situation cannot occur in your situation?

Comment: such situation can't occur

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I have one more question. In your sample values, 3 columns of `ID, Name, Agreement` are used. But in your script, are 4 columns of `timestamp, ID, Name, Agreement` used? I cannot understand about the relationship between your sample values and your script. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal and your current issue?

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, I have a form in which a user submits several information and the id is generated through that form, this form sends the information to the sheet, then an email is sent to another person containing the ID, the other user should fill a form containing only two field one for the id and one for the agreement an also this form submits to the same spreadsheet

Comment: so I'm just trying to link both responses into the same row

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `so I'm just trying to link both responses into the same row`, I can understand from your sample value. I'm worry about whether the values should be retrieved from the cells "A2:C" for your actual situation. So I asked about it. As the sample script, when the values are retrieved from the cells "A2:C" and the converted values are put to the cells  "A2:C", this is the same with the result you expect?

Comment: I found a solution, I will post it now please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this function and it actually merged two rows with the same ID value successfully,
I will further test it for any issues

```
function mergeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var newData = [];
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for (var j in newData) {
      if(row[0] == newData[j][0]){
        duplicate = true;
        newData[j][87]=(row[87]);
        Logger.log(newData[j][87])
        Logger.log(row[87])

      }
    }
    if (!duplicate) {
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```